# In Project Directory While running "npm install" getting error as " Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native, npm

**Here is My Terminal Log**

[image]

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

> npm ERR!     /Users/sukumar/.npm/_logs/2017-09-15T05_42_40_799Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue.

Check this : 
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17858